# change the type of the field in the SELECT statement

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I want to change the datatype of a column in the SELECT statement. The change of the datatype I want is from decimal to whole number. I want to discard the decimal portion of the number.

Please tell me how to do it.

Comment: I want to discard the decimal portion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `floor()` function. `floor(111.222)` will return `111`. This doesn't round the number, so `floor(111.999)` will also return `111` (which is different from the behaviour of `round()`).

> By using the floor function will the data type be converted from decimal to whole number.

Using `floor()` converts the data into a whole number. If you actually want to change the datatype (why?) you will need to cast the projected column to an integer:

```
cast(floor(111.999) as integer) as whole_num
```

Note that casting on its own will **round** the output.

SQLFiddle demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/385f79/3).

---

> in the condition i want to write a equality expression ... ) but Table1.id is decimal and Table2.id is whole number

It really doesn't matter in such a case. Basically Oracle has one datatype for numeric data, number. There are aliases (decimal, int, etc) but these are freely convertible to number. That is, `111.000 = 111`. So you can write your join exactly as you showed without any need for datatype conversion.

The only thing you need to worry about is if the decimal ID isn't a clean integer, that is if `id != floor(id)`. This shouldn't be a problem provided the table is populated properly (and you're not using one of the floating point datatypes).

Comment: Quick question : By using the floor function will the data type be converted from decimal to whole number.?

Comment: My problem statement is i want to perform Left Outer Join ( in select statement) and in the condition i want to write a equality expression ( i.e., table1. id = table2.id) but Table1.id is decimal and Table2.id is whole number. So i want to convert the data type of table1.id to whole number

Comment: No but the CAST(... AS integer) does.

Comment: i wrote the select statement as " SELECT cast( B Id as integer) as b_id FROM DBO_Table1) t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM DBM.Table2) t2 ON (t1.b_Id = t2.b_no) "                                                                                  Here DBO is oracle database and DBM is mysql database                                                                              But i get the error as "Oracle database error 905: ORA-00905: missing keyword"

Comment: `ORA-00905` always indicates a syntax error. As posted here you have **two** syntax errors. You're missing the underscore(?) in the projection of the first subquery - it should be `b_id`. And you have an unmatched right parenthesis after `DBO_Table1)`. Although maybe that's not the whole query, so who can tell?